# How to add Pages to Main Nav Magento 2

Tags: magento2, navigation

How do I link my cms pages to a main navigation bar at the top of the page on Magento 2?

If I want to eliminate the "home" link and only have the logo redirect to the store view homepage how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be:

1. Create a new category and call it **"Home"**.
2. SEO Settings for this category: URL slug **"startpage"** or something else.
3. Rewrite **"/startpage"** to **"/"**.
4. Move it to first position.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

No way to use admin to create home menu, but you can customize code to make it.

First, you need to create a category name "Home".

Next, copy this file: `vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\topmenu.phtml` and place it to `app\design\frontend\Your_Vendor\Your_Theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html`

Open this file, you can see a line same that:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_menu; ?>
```

Change to:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo str_replace('/home.html', '',$_menu); ?>
```

Done. Hope this help you.